# Update .class file in Eclipse SDK

Tags: java, android

I want to make some changes in the SmsManager.class file in Eclipse SDK , I couldn't update the .class as I don't know how to compile the SmsManager.java. Please suggest a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search for SmsManager.java file in your disk. Then you can make a new class from that code and modify it or even extend that class. 
I found that class in `android-sdk\sources\android-14\android\telephony\gsm.`

Comment: I found that java file but I cann't compile that file, can you suggest me how to compile that file in eclipse.I found the class file in android.jar\android\telephony\smsManager.class , but don't know how to edit and that file

Comment: To edit that file you have to copy it to your project in eclipse. Find it on your disk and drag it to your srs file on your project. Then you can compile it.